# Displaying the converstaion that occured that day in a SignalR chat application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, chat

I'm doing the "Getting Started with SignalR 2 and MVC 5" tutorial in www.asp.net(http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc), and in it I developpped a chat application using mvc and signalR
The problem with the chat is that once you start chatting you see only the messages starting from that time onward. I want to be able to see the conversation that occured that day.
I already have the whole chat conversation in a table "Chat":

```
public class Chat    
    {
        public   int id { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }

        public String name { get; set; }
        public String message { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the chat view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Chat";
}
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdherent.cshtml";
}

<h2>Chat</h2>
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="message" />
    <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
    <input type="hidden" value=@ViewBag.Name id="displayname" />
    <ul id="discussion"></ul>
</div>
@section scripts {
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--The jQuery library is required and is referenced by default in _Layout.cshtml. -->
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.-->
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
            chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
                // Add the message to the page.
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name)
                    + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
            };


            // Set initial focus to message input box.
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
        // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
        function htmlEncode(value) {
            var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
            return encodedValue;
        }
    </script>
}
```

The controller:

```
public ActionResult Chat()
        {
            Member member = (Member)Session["logedmem"];
            String name = member.name; 
            ViewBag.Name = name;
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: How do you store the conversation in a table? Could you please also share that?

Comment: Basically you need to have a method on the repository to give you the last 100 (here any number that suits you) messages between these two clients. Then have a dependency of the repository in your class and pass the data to the clients through a hub.

Is it any clearer?

Comment: I stored it by changing the Send method in the Hub class to this:                    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
           
            Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
            Chat chat = new Chat();
            chat.date = DateTime.Now;
            chat.nom = name;
            chat.message = message;
            ChatService chatService = new ChatService();
            chatService.CreateChat(chat);


        }
    }

Comment: @Matei_Radu I already have the conversation from the last day. I just wanted to know if there were another way using SignalR. I'm using a partial view of the list of entity "Chat"' from the last day.